# Assembly Language - What is the register of an temp string input

Tags: assembly, emulation, emu8086

I have been comparing an fixed string and an input string. But its hard to figure what is the register of the input one, is it `al`, `ah` or whatever. I'm just a beginner and this is a painful language for a programmer lol jk. please help I really appreciate it thanks :)

```
mov dx, offset temp             ;string input
mov ah, 0ah
int 21h     

mov bl, "a"                     ;condition
cmp al, bl 
jne aw

mov dx, offset msgTrue          ;true
mov ah, 09
int 21h  

aw:                             ;false
mov dx, offset msgFalse
mov ah, 09
int 21h 


ret
    msg  db 10, 13, "           *         ************************************       *****$"
    msg1 db 10, 13, "          ***        *            Ticketing System      *        ***$"
    msg2 db 10, 13, "         *****       ************************************         *$" 
    msg3 db 10, 13, "                          ==========================$" 
    msg4 db 10, 13, "                          =  (a)Land               =$" 
    msg5 db 10, 13, "                          =  (b)Water              =$"
    msg6 db 10, 13, "                          =  (c)Air                =$" 
    msg7 db 10, 13, "                          ==========================$" 
    msg8 db 10, 13, "                           Choose Travel Type: $"
    temp db 2, 0, 3 dup("$") 

    msgTrue db 10, 13, "                           You selected Land$"
    msgFalse db 10, 13, "                           Invalid Input$"
```

Comment: Note that you don't need to label `msg1` / `msg2` etc.  You can just have unlabelled `db` lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is in memory, where you asked the system call to put it.  See Ralf's answer.

Check the input like so:

```
    mov   dx, offset temp             ; input buffer
    mov   ah, 0ah                     ; buffered input syscall
    int   21h     

    ; select one of two messages to print
    mov   dx, offset msgTrue
    cmp   byte ptr [temp+2], 'a'      ; compare the first byte of user input
    je  .true
    mov   dx, offset msgFalse         ; conditionally skip this instruction
.true:

    mov ah, 09                        ; print string syscall
    int 21h
```

Notice how the `mov ah` / `int 0x21` code only appears once, and the branch only skips over a single instruction.  You could do it with `cmov` on a modern CPU, but `cmov` annoyingly doesn't have an immediate-source encoding.

See the comments on Ralf's answer for criticism of the bloated code that results from not just using immediate operands with `cmp`.  You tie up a lot fewer registers this way, too, when using assemble-time constants.

---

Another option (instead of `mov dx, offset msgFalse`) would be `add dx, offset msgFalse - msgTrue`, which makes the immediate operand a small number (fitting within the -128 .. 127 range for using the imm8 encoding).  It doesn't save any code bytes in 16bit code, though, because `mov dx, imm16` is 3 bytes (dedicated opcode for every dest register), and `add dx, imm8` is also three bytes (no dedicated opcode).  This would save bytes in 32bit code, where addresses are 32bits.

Answer (score 2):

You use syscall 0Ah (buffered input) http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html#ah0a so the data you read is in **temp** (the buffer)

0Ah reads n bytes from STDIN into a buffer

`mov bx, OFFSET buffer`  pushes the address of buffer (here temp) in bx, this is needed for 0Ah

To fix the number of bytes read you can use e.g. `mov  byte [bx],15`

see also this http://www.fysnet.net/kbbuffio.htm

```
mov bl, 'a'                     ;condition
cmp al, bl 
jne aw
```

compares two 8-bit values (char), see this http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_35.html (AL,AH is 8 bit, AX is 16 bit and EAX is 32 bit (Extended AX))

See this https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/X86_Architecture#General-purpose_registers_(16-bit_naming_conventions) for the 8-/16-/32-/64-bit naming conventions

This can be used to read the read input byte from the input buffer *temp* and compare it:

```
val DB 'a'
mov al, val                    ;condition
mov bx, OFFSET temp            ; address of temp in bx: bx is a pointer to first byte in temp now
;alternatively you can use  lea bx, [temp] 
add bx, 2                     ; structure of input buffer (here temp) http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html#dosbuf
mov dl, byte [bx]              ; writes the byte [bx] points to in dl - [bx] dereferences bx - the byte command treats bx as a char* - see https://www.cs.uaf.edu/2006/fall/cs301/lecture/10_02_pointer.html
cmp al, dl 
jne aw
```

Comment: why not point out that `cmp al, 'a'` would be simpler?  No need to tie up bl when an immediate will work the same.  There's even a special encoding for cmp-immediate-with-al, so it's only a 2 byte instruction even with the immediate.  Also, what do you think is wrong with `mov bl, 'a'`?  Most assemblers let you use character constants anywhere an integer constant can appear.  Multi-char constants produce multi-byte integers.

Comment: Still really clunky compared to `cmp byte [temp], 'a'` / `jne`.  Also note that 16bit effective addresses can't use dx as a base or index, only BX/BP + SI/DI.  [16bit can't use a SIB byte, so they have to jam all the addressing modes into the mod/rm byte](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34058400/224132).  This is just one of the many reasons 16bit code sucks and is a waste of time to learn.  (Those restrictions don't exist in other modes).

Comment: I wasn't going to, but I can't leave inefficient code alone. >.<  Thanks for sorting out the format of the input buffer.  I'm not a DOS guy, and have no interest in learning DOS system calls, other than to try to help people on SO.  Oh, BTW, `offset temp + '3'` is not the same as `offset temp + 3`.  You're adding the ascii encoding >.<.  And you should do it at assemble time, since it's an assemble-time constant, rather than doing it at runtime.  And shouldn't it be `+2`?  The first user-input character goes after the two count bytes, right?

Comment: You are right it is +2. When reading first  it thought  byte 02 in the buffer also has 'administrative function' (and then begin the user bytes...)

Comment: Other things  still wrong with your code: `[dx]` is not a valid effective address.  Your code won't assemble.  Use `bx`, `bp`, `si`, or `di`.  e.g. `mov si, offset temp + 2` / `cmp byte ptr [si], 'a'`.  ([16bit does allow displacement-only effective addresses](http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~celio/mc404s2-03/addr_modes/intel_addr.html#HEADING2-26).  32bit effective addresses are the same, except without the limitations, and you can scale the index.  (see the link in my earlier comment for a writeup I did on 32bit EAs)).  You can waste instructions putting things in regs if you like, though :P

Comment: It would be `lea bx, [temp]`.  LEA's source is always an effective address.  At least your un-commented code should work now, even if it is even less efficient than the OPs. :P